# Hold reusable Jenkins Build configuration entirely within project being built

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My company is working on a medical-grade SAAS app.  We use Jenkins and have a whole pipeline of building, deploying to the cloud, integration testing there, and un-deploying.

Because we're falling under Federal regulation, *everything* gets audited, including the build process.

Currently, we use Jenkins 1.x with the Job DSL Plugin, allowing us to automate the configuration of our Jenkins jobs.  This isn't very auditable, as the configuration of Jenkins still changes, so we might not build the same way today as we did a month ago.  We really need to get the "how to build this" knowledge out of Jenkins configuration and into the same Git repository as our sources.

I've been investigating the use of Jenkins 2.x with Pipelines.  I've started to re-write our old DSL jobs in Pipeline format and store them in the same Git repo as the sources.  However, we need reusability.  Multiple steps often have the same code within them, and we even need multiple pipelines (one for build, deploy, and test and another to just build, for instance).  Therefore, I want my code to be reusable.

I was hoping that I could just add a directory from my Git repo to the pipeline classpath and store all the common stuff there, but it appears impossible.  I suspect that this is part of some sort of sandbox security thing, but how less secure would such classes be than the jenkins file within the same Git workspace?

Jenkins has the 'shared library' concept, but that defeats the purpose--it stores the build configuration in Jenkins rather than within the source code.

How do I do code reuse in a Jenkins pipeline, so that an auditor can see all (or at least most) of the Jenkins build code within the source tree?

---

[EDIT] I need to make one more requirement clear.  I need to change the way that Jenkins builds the project based on the version of the source which I am building.  When we cut a milestone, for instance, we need the milestone builds to always build the same way even when we evolve the mainline builds.  That's why I'm so gung-ho on keeping all the Jenkins configuration that I can in the same repository as the project being built.

Comment: Is it not possible to create a submodule with just the Jenkins build script and include this submodule in every project to reuse it?

Comment: I don't see how.  To get include to work, I need to get the submodule in the classpath.  To do that, I need to know the absolute directory, which requires checking the environment, which is forbidden and denied by the plugin.  If someone knows how to get such includes to work, however, that would solve my problem.

Comment: [Pipeline shared groovy libraries plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Shared+Groovy+Libraries+Plugin). I use it. We have one Git repository with util functions and will add a library for each different build type (like C#, NPM ....) which is reusable between many microservices and helps keep the jenkinsfile in each repo extremely small. Do you really have a hard requirement to have everything in the same repo? Couldn't you have one pipeline library repo? Check out the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and what can be done with it.

Comment: After some work, I found that this actually works.  I'd accept this if it was an answer.  What I didn't realize was that the build code can choose which _version_ of the library to use.  In my case, I can specify a library version by SHA, and any auditors can follow that SHA to see the whole library, regardless of how Jenkins is configured.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use a plugin like `thinBackup` and have the tool backup your Jenkins configuration on a schedule that runs after your build schedule.

The backups could be saved into your source control folder and archived there with a submission.

A nice side effect is that you could always restore the complete Jenkins configuration for a specific build that you did.

[Please see this link.](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/thinBackup)

Comment: This could improve auditability, but doesn't allow the source to control how it's built. Having Jenkins write to the SCM repo you are building is also problematic--it leads to build loops, where Jenkins commits to SCM, then sees an SCM change and builds it, ad infinitum.  I could safe a thin backup alongside the other build artifacts, but that only solves half the problem.

Comment: Maybe your use case is not clear enough to me, but can you save the configuration into a separate repository for this purpose? So no builds are triggered. Also the way it's saved are xml files which you can modify before reimporting.